# can't add background image in HTML ( spring boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

My browser says failed to load resources when add background image in thyme HTML and add css external file in spring boot and also tried background-image=url("/image/background3.jpg");in url and  last option used the src/main/resources/static/images/background3.jpg

[In Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ede7C.jpg)-background3.jpg:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aywjm.jpg)-src-main-resources-static-images-background3.jpg

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIM6M.jpg).-body{
background-image: url('background3.jpg');

}

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVGgT.jpg)-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
```

[when i changed the color instead of image, background color appears .why not the image display]

Comment: Please include code, not images of code: see [Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Edit the question and include code fragments.

Comment: i added the image code in text box